# jQuery post works in Chrome but not IE or FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, internet-explorer

```
$.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(json) {
            alert('red');
            AddItemAjax(json);
        }, "json");
```

This works in Chrome but not IE or FF.. it fails to just run this line of code. Ive made sure it gets to this point but fails when trying the post! (note i have the alert('red'); to let me know if it run it fine)

Comment: This may not help you but IE8 has an incredible javascript debugger (breakpoints and all)

Comment: I think you will need to tell us about 'AddItemAjax' if we stand a chance of figuring out what's (not) happening.

Comment: is the jquery post function failing or the post itself e.g webserver returns 404? if you dont know plz install firebug (for FF) and check your post target, the response and the result.

Comment: What does Firebug show you about the XMLHttpRequest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks guys but i found out the issue.. 
"$(this).attr("action")" was returning a null.. and Chrome didn't have a problem with this but everything else (FF and IE8) did!!!

but thanks for the help!